# 360 degrees spherical mobile app

Tags: android, cordova, ios7

A client asked me if we can make a mobile app that can merge images together to get a spherical preview not panoramic, but it's like you're sitting inside a sphere and watching in 360 degrees.
My question is can it be made using PhoneGap, AngularJS or jQuery...

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few JS libraries out there. You can try:

- [Krpano](http://krpano.com/docu/html5/#intro) - [Demo](http://krpano.com/krpano.html?xml=tours/corfu/tour.xml&html5=prefer%20css3d)
- [jQuery Reel](http://jquery.vostrel.cz/reel) - [Demo](http://test.vostrel.net/jquery.reel/example/panorama-orientable-stitched/)
- [Leanorama](https://github.com/leandigo/leanorama) - [Demo](http://leandigo.github.io/leanorama/)
- [PanoVR](https://ggnome.com/wiki/HTML5_Output_(Pano2VR)) - [Demo](https://ggnome.com/samples/pano2vr_4/tour/) (Commercial)

It depends how 'cross platform' you want to get. Most libraries require some form of CSS3 or WebGL support. And these only got stable after iOS 7.0 and Android 4.4

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Krpano is the exact effect I wanna do, but it requires installation of external files, it's for Desktop use.

Comment: Yes if you the `MAKE VTOUR (NORMAL) droplet` command it will generate the HTML5 files + js. Reference: http://krpano.com/docu/tutorials/quickstart/#top